# How to get the array textcontent defined by the value

Tags: javascript, html

Hi im trying to get the array textcontent value through my console.log but it says undefined.

```
    function clickHandler(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();

   let targ= evt.target;
   if (itemsArray.includes(targ)){
    selectedView.value = targ.dataset.value;
      itemsArray[0].textContent = targ.textContent 
      console.log(itemsArray.textContent);
     } 
    }
```

Comment: i think this should be like this `var itemsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(items,0);`

Comment: it still says itemsArray.contains is not a function

Comment: `contains` is not an array method in javascript you can use `itemsArray.includes(targ)`

Comment: oh okay, well now i can click on the li but it is not spitting out which one i clicked to the value